# How to make button width match parent?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to know that how can I set a width to **match parent** layout width

```
new Container(
  width: 200.0,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
  child: new RaisedButton(
    child: new Text(
      "Submit",
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      )
    ),
    colorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    onPressed: () {
      _loginAttempt(context);
    },
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
),
```

I know about little bit on `Expanded` widget but `Expanded` expands view to both direction, i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps a Column instead?

Comment: Yes I attach column instead of Container but width of button is Wrap Content how can stretch width to parent

Comment: You can simply use a FlatButton and wrap it inside a container and add width of the container to screen width by using mediaquery look for my answer below

Answer (score 448, accepted):

**Update:**

With Flutter 2.0 `RaisedButton` is deprecated and replaced by `ElevatedButton`. you can use `minimumSize` like this:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(40), // fromHeight use double.infinity as width and 40 is the height
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('Text Of Button'),
)
```

---

Old answer for Flutter less than 2.0:

The correct solution would be to use the `SizedBox.expand` widget, which enforces its `child` to match its parent's size.

```dart
SizedBox.expand(
  child: RaisedButton(...),
)
```

There are many alternatives, which allows for more or less customization:

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  // height: double.infinity,
  child: RaisedButton(...),
)
```

or using a `ConstrainedBox`

```dart
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
  child: RaisedButton(...),
)
```

Comment: SizedBox.expand will make the button take full width and height, which is not the question about. The question is about a button covering full width only not height.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Vinoth's comment is valid. Since this is now the accepted answer, could you add the right constructors for SizedBox to specifically expand only the width?

Comment: I'm receiving this error `Failed assertion: line 1645 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.`

Comment: Why couldn't we just change the width of the container like this: `Container(width: double.infinity)` instead of wrapping it with another widget like `SizedBox`. It's much simpler to read and brings the same results.

Comment: So if I have to understand what the Size.fromHeight exactly does, what's a good place to learn?

Comment: ` double.infinity` will getting the full width thank you

Comment: Still works `SizedBox` on flutter version 3.13.3

Answer (score 52):

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: RaisedButton(...),
),
```

Answer (score 49):

After some research, I found out some solution, and thanks to @Günter Zöchbauer,

I used column instead of Container and

set the property to column **CrossAxisAlignment.stretch** to Fill match parent of Button

```
    new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                new RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text(
                      "Submit",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )
                  ),
                  colorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _loginAttempt(context);
                  },
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: `Column`/`Row` shouldn't be used for single-child layout. Use the single-child alternative instead. Such as `Align`, `SizedBox`, and similar.

Answer (score 42):

The size attribute can be provided using `ButtonTheme` with `minWidth: double.infinity`

```
ButtonTheme(
  minWidth: double.infinity,
  child: MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('Raised Button'),
  ),
),
```

or after https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/19416 landed

```
MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: SizedBox.expand(
    width: double.infinity, 
    child: Text('Raised Button'),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 32):

The simplest way is to use a `FlatButton` wrapped inside a `Container`, The button by default takes the size of its parent and so assign a desired width to the `Container`.

```
            Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 60,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    color: Colors.red[300],
                    child: Text(
                      "Button",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                        fontSize: 22.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You can set match parent of the widget by

**1) set width to **double.infinity** :**

```
new Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
          child: new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text(
                "Submit",
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                )
            ),
            colorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            onPressed: () {
              _loginAttempt(context);
            },
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
```

**2) Use MediaQuery:**

```
new Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
          child: new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text(
                "Submit",
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                )
            ),
            colorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            onPressed: () {
              _loginAttempt(context);
            },
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: You have a typo in "MediaLQuery", I can't edit a single character ;)

Answer (score 8):

For `match_parent` you can use

```
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity, // match_parent
  child: RaisedButton(...)
)
```

For any particular value you can use

```
SizedBox(
  width: 100, // specific value
  child: RaisedButton(...)
)
```

Answer (score 7):

@Mohit Suthar,

Found one of the best solution for **match parent** to **width** as well as **height** as below

```
new Expanded(
          child: new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius:
                      const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(8.0)),
                  border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0)),
              child: new Text("TejaDroid")),
        ),
```

Here you can check that the `Expanded` Controller **acquire whole** remain **width** and **height**.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to give match-parent width or height in the given code above.

```
...
width: double.infinity,
height: double.infinity,
...
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to make full width button. But I think you should understand the concept of making full width widgets in different scenarios:

When you are using nested widgets then it is hard to identify width of parent widget. Simply you can't specify width in nested widgets. So you should use either Expanded or Column with CrossAxisAlignment as Strech.

In other cases, you can use media query width or double.infinity.

Here are some examples for Nested widgets and single widget:

**First:**

```
Expanded(   // This will work for nested widgets and will take width of first parent widget.
  child: MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text("Button Text"),
    color: Colors.indigo,
    textColor: Colors.white,
  )
)
```

**Second:**

```
Column( // This will not work if parent widget Row.
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: const Text("Button Text"),
      color: Colors.indigo,
      textColor: Colors.white,
    )
  ]
)
```

**Third:**

```
ButtonTheme( // if use media query, then will not work for nested widgets.
  minWidth: double.infinity,  //Or use 'width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width'
  child: MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text("Button Text"),
    color: Colors.indigo,
    textColor: Colors.white,
  )
)
```

**Forth:**

```
SizedBox( // if use media query, then will not work for nested widgets.
  width: double.infinity, //Or use 'width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width'
  child: MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text("Button Text"),
    color: Colors.indigo,
    textColor: Colors.white,
  )
)
```

**Fifth:**

```
Container( // if use media query, then will not work for nested widgets.
  width: double.infinity, //Or use 'width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width'
  child: MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text("Button Text"),
    color: Colors.indigo,
    textColor: Colors.white,
  )
)
```

From my point of view, recommended will be the First one. Also you can change `MaterialButton` to `ElevatedButton` or `TextButton` or `RaisedButton (Depreciated)` or any other widget.

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 3):

you can do that with **MaterialButton**

```
MaterialButton(
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
     minWidth: double.infinity,
     onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("Btn"),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `fixedSize.width` of the `ButtonStyle` to a very large number, like `double.maxFinite`. You can also use `Size.fromWidth()` constructor if you don't want to specify the height:

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: const Text('Button'),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    fixedSize: const Size.fromWidth(double.maxFinite),
  ),
),
```

### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0462c227aecd362cb82f152b54bccda3&null_safety=true)

Answer (score 2):

The most basic approach is using Container by define its width to infinite. See below example of code

```
Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    child:FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
            //your action here
        },
        child: Text("Button"),

    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
         OutlineButton(
              onPressed: () {
                logInButtonPressed(context);
              },
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                child: Text(
                  “Log in”,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Something like this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Following code work for me

```
       ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: double.infinity,
            child: RaisedButton(child: Text("Click!!", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),), color: Colors.pink, onPressed: () {}))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me in a self contained widget.

```
  Widget signinButton() {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: double.infinity,
      child: new FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        color: Colors.green[400],
        textColor: Colors.white,
        child: Text('Flat Button'),
      ),
    );
  }

// It can then be used in a class that contains a widget tree.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me.

```
    SizedBox(
             width: double.maxFinite,
             child: RaisedButton(
                 materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                 child: new Text("Button 2"),
                 color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                 onPressed: () => debugPrint("Button 2"),
              ),
     ),
```

Answer (score 1):

`RaisedButton(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [Text('Submit')],
  )
)`

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

With **Flutter 2.0** `RaisedButton` is deprecated and replaced by `ElevatedButton`.

`minimumSize` property of `ElevatedButton` widget exactly does that.

**Example code:**

```
ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.green,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
              elevation: 3,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
              minimumSize: Size(100, 40), //////// HERE
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('MyButton'),
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  Size(double.maxFinite, 50.0),
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Upgrade to Premium'),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `ListTile` also works as well, since a list fills the entire width:

```
ListTile(
  title: new RaisedButton(...),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 new SizedBox(
  width: 100.0,
     child: new RaisedButton(...),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-100,
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your (child widget having a fixed width) with a center widget. This will center your widget:

```
Center(child:Container(width:250,child:TextButton(child:Text("Button Name),),)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  child:  FilledButton(
          onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Save Sale")),
)
```

[image: Preview]

Answer (score -1):

TRY

```
Flexible(
 child: Row(
  children: [
    ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text("love you}"),
   ),
  ],
 ),
),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.