# Flutter ButtonBar Children Size

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-layout

I am working on an app in Flutter, and I want to use `ButtonBar`. however, when trying to make the children utilize the space the buttons only utilize the minimal space

```
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ButtonBar(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Save'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtpPage()));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ButtonBar(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Save'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtpPage()));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Any idea how to get the button to utilize more space

Comment: I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014342/button-width-match-parent-flutter/50017126#50017126) and it does work.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the button size with `ButtonTheme` property

[Raised buttons have a minimum size of 88.0 by 36.0 which can be overridden with ButtonTheme.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html)

Secondly,

You can try to wrap the buttons with `Expanded` widget

```
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ButtonBar(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtpPage()));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try the size, but the expanded does not work for ButtonBar children

Comment: Expanded widget can be use inside Row and Columns