# How to set flutter bottom sheet height fit with inner content?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how to control flutter bottom sheet height with its inner content without fixed height? totally I just want a height change with its inner content size

Comment: please share a code

Comment: Go through the this link. I am sure it helps you
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014342/button-width-match-parent-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ConstrainedBox` give a minimum and maximum height and width as you need and the child of the `ConsrainedBox` should be your bottom sheet `container` and you are good to go.

Here is the youtube link on [ConstrainedBox](https://youtu.be/o2KveVr7adg).

Here is more how you can deal with box  constraints: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints