# Can't change the height of a button in flutter

Tags: flutter, button, dart, resize, materialbutton

I'm new to flutter. I'm trying to insert to the "AppBar" a simple "contained button" with text on it. 
(For example the material design "contained button" [here](https://material.io/components/buttons/#))

The problem is that no matter what height I insert in the Constructor, the button still fills the full height of the AppBar.

I can visibly solve the problem with setting padding as I did in the example below, but it frustrates me that I don't understand why I can't change the button's height itself. 
I tried also to wrap it with a container or a sizedBox like shown in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014342/button-width-match-parent-flutter/50017126#50017126) but it didn't make any visible change (still the button filled the whole appBar height)

I would really appreciate it if also someone could explain to me why the code acts like that.

```
      appBar: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Text(widget.title),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7.0, bottom: 7),
            child: Container(
              width: 80,
              child: FlatButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 90, 128, 1),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Button')
              ),
            )
        ),
        ]
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `AppBar()` is following the [material design guidelines for AppBar](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/).

Also this is related with the Material `Scaffold()` widget.

You can take a look at this documentation

- [AppBar Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)
- [Scaffold Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)

In this *particular case*, I think the best way to control the height is using a `Padding()` around. You can erase the Container in your code.

```
appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    title: Text(widget.title),
    actions: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FlatButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            ),
            color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 90, 128, 1),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('Button')),
      ),
    ]),
```

You can control the full AppBar size using `PreferredSize()`, but this has no relation with the buttons height.